# Execute SQL task to Insert Date with Parameter

Tags: sql, ssis

[Bypass Set to True and Issue Resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S22MF.jpg)I am Using Execute SQL task to Insert Date into Staging Table and I am facing the below error:

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query

`DECLARE @Counter VARCHAR(15)=?
INSERT INTO tblFor..." failed with the following error: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.`

Comment: Include screenshots and code of the SQL Task in the question

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Hi All Noted Issue has been Resolved after setting ByPassPrepare to TRUE

Answer (score 0):

if you want to manage your variables better use expressions : 
[image]

and here how to declare your variables from

[image]

ones there you can create your variables with type and value if you want